# Google Place Picker on Android - limit area/radius

Tags: android, google-places-api

Is there a way to limit Google Place Picker area that user is able to pick his/her place?

Something like radius from current location.

Comment: When you say 'Google Place Picker' do you mean a `Marker`?

Comment: No - I mean Place Picker from Places API - https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is documentation to control the selection in the actual `Place Picker` intent, but you could do it in the `onActivityResult. Here is an example:

```
int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
String toastMsg;
Location selectedLocation = new Location(provider);
Location currentLocation = new Location(provider);
double maxDistance = 10;
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);

            selectedLocation.setLatitude(place.getLatLng().latitude);
            selectedLocation.setLongitude(place.getLatLng().longitude);
            if(selectedLocation.distanceTo(currentLocation) > maxDistance) {
                toastMsg = "Invalid selection, please reselect your place";
                // Runs the selector again
                PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
                startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
            } else {
                // Result is fine
                toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

You can change `maxDistance` to the maximum distance you want the user's selection to be from their location. Hope it helps!